# How to recover value of DataRow when manual validation fails?

Tags: vb.net, datarow

I have a .Net application with some DataRows and DataTables.

The datatables has some constraints (Columns not null, Unique columns, Size of the columns, ...)

When the user types some data, the following code is executed. When this code runs, it raises the default data verification against the columns from the datatable (Columns not null, Unique columns, Size of the columns, ...)

In addition to the default validation, I add some business logic checks...

```
sub ValidationProcedure
    Dim MyRow as DataRowView = something

    'End edit the user inputs
    Try
        MyRow.EndEdit()
    catch Ex as exception
        Msgbox("Please correct the errors")
        MyRow.CancelEdit()
        exit sub 
    End try

    'Clear previous errors
    MyRow.ClearErrors

    'Business logic checks
    If MyRow.Item("C1") > MyRow.Item("C2") then 'Or whatever condition
        Msgbox("Please correct the errors")
        MyRow.SetColumnError(ColumnId, "C1 should be lower than C2")
        MyRow.CancelEdit()
    end if 
end sub
```

This code works fine however, when the default validation succeeds and the business logic validation fails, the value of the Row doesn't return to their initial value since the EndEdit succeeded.
I'm expecting the row to go back to it's original state before calling the validation

Does anyone know how to return the row to it's original state before calling the validation procedure ?

Cheers

Comment: Could you run business validation before default validation? Or hang on to a copy of the row after default validation, and set myrow back to the copy if business validation fails?

Comment: Surely the thing to do is to put the call to `EndEdit` at the end of that method.